# Does TDengine Python connector support executemany?

Tags: python, database, tdengine

I'm currently using TDengine and Python to store time-series data.

I tried Python connector.

```
conn = taos.connect()
conn.execute(“…”)
```

It’s OK.  However, the performance is not very good. Does TDengine Python connector support `executemany` and binding  parameters?

Or is there another way to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

[Article](https://tdengine.medium.com/efficient-data-writing-in-tdengine-9f6f2a119761#:%7E:text=TDengine%20supports%20multi%2Dthread%20parallel,thread%20switching%20brings%20extra%20overhead.) on improving the performance of data writing into TDengine.

Appears a combination of [batch writes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) and [multi-thread parallel writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) with certain limits can improve speed but that will depend on your run environment.

Before you do anything I'd put some decent [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) in place so you know if you're getting improvements.

***Edit:*** [Also section from TDengine docs directly related to High Performance data writing.](https://docs.tdengine.com/develop/insert-data/high-volume/)